how to get table rows that are not in another table with a condition?
i want take typens from table 2 which are not in the first table and fulfill the conditions
i have table 1
+----+---------------+-------+
| ID | vacancyTypeID | orgId |
+----+---------------+-------+
|  1 |             4 |    25 |
|  2 |             2 |    25 |
|  3 |             3 |    25 |
|  4 |             4 |    24 |
|  5 |             1 |    22 |
+----+---------------+-------+

and table 2
+------------+----+
| typen      | id |
+------------+----+
| teacher    |  1 |
| teacher 2  |  2 |
| teacher 3  |  3 |
| teacher 4 |  4 |
| teacher 5  |  5 |
+------------+----+

i want get
all typen from table2 which are not in table 2 for  with orgid = 25
i get nothing when try this
SELECT table2.*
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON (table1.vacancyTypeID=table2.id)
where table1.vacancyTypeID is null table1.orgId = 25;

but i need
+------------+----+
| typen      | id |
+------------+----+
| teacher    |  1 |
| teacher 5  |  5 |
+------------+----+


Your questions is very confusing.  Why use "table 1" and "table 2" if you're using real table names in the query?

Please don't change table names to meaningless table1 and table2. Please change them back to something meaningful.

I think this does what you want.  Pick all the orgs where the id is not in the other list:
SELECT * FROM OrganizationTypes
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT vacancyTypeID FROM Vacancys WHERE orgId=25
);

